# Accessing elements of lists, and calling their fuctions

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, generics

Here is Customer class:

```
class Customer:

    def __init__(self, timestamp, cid, item_count):

        self.time_stamp = timestamp
        self.customer_name = cid
        self.item_count = item_count

    def checkout(self, new_timestamp):
        self.time_stamp = new_timestamp

    def get_cus_name(self):
        return self.customer_name
```

If I create an empty list of Customer objects like:

```
customers = [Customer]
```

And then somewhere else I try to call Customer methods in a loop like:

```
def checkout_customer(self, cid):
        for cus in self.customers:
            if cus.get_cus_name == cid:
                cus.checkout(self.cur_num_customers + 7)
```

why do I get an error when I try to call cus.checkout? My ide tells me that it expects a Customer but got an int. Why doesn't it pass itself into the 'self' arg here?

However if I just create a Customer object and directly call its methods, it works fine:

```
def foo(self):
        cus = Customer(1,'pop',2)
        cus.checkout(23)
```

This is my first time learning python, and ive been stuck trying to figure out lists, and accessing its members. Perhaps my initialization of `self.custormers = [Customer]` is incorrect?

EDIT:

In my constructor of tester class I create an empty list like this:

```
self.customer = [Customer]
```

I am able to add customers no problem:

```
def add_custormer(self, customer):
   self.customers.append(customer)
```

My problem is not adding customers, but accessing their methods once they are in a list. Doing something like this self.customers[0].checkout(1,'pop',2) gives me an error "Expected type 'Customer' got int".

Comment: That's not a list of customers, it's a list of references to the Customer class itself.

Comment: Yes your initialization of `customers` list was incorrect. You just placed the `Customer` class "blueprint" inside a list, its not the real customer. You must do something like `self.customers = [Customer(1232144234, 123, 2)]`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of the class where checkout_customer lives but I am assuming you declare the list self.customers somewhere in it.

`self.costumers = []`

If you intend to add an element Customer to the list you should use something like: `self.customers.append(Customer(x,y,z))` since you want to add a new customer to the list and when doing so you are required to initialize the Customer class.

I didn't try the code but I believe something like this should work:

`def foo(self):
     self.customers.append(Customer(1,'pop',2))
     self.checkout_customers(23)`

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. I declared the empty like like so: self.customers = [Customer]. Say I add 10 customers into the list. My problem is if I want to call functions from the list like self.customers[0].function1(). I edited my original post for further clarification.

Comment: @Infodayne Thanks for the clarification. I think you should declare the empty array as `self.costumers = []`. That way when you pass a int it will return a costumer object